# Remove additional space surrounding radio fields created using hyperref

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I am using XeLaTeX with hyperref to create a form which contains radio fields, and I have noticed that the radio fields I have created using `\ChoiceMenu` each have horizontal space preceding and following the field itself. This is an issue for me because I am purposely creating fields without labels, as I am instead adding and spacing the labels separately using `\hskip` and boxes to contain each label, so I do not want any space to be automatically added for me. The following example uses `\fbox`es to show this extra space, which appears when I create a radio field but not when I create other types of hyperref fields:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Using \texttt{\textbackslash ChoiceMenu} with \texttt{radio=true} adds extra horizontal space before and after the field:

    \fbox{hello}\fbox{\ChoiceMenu[name=testfield1, radio=true, bordersep=0pt, height=36bp, width=36bp]{}{=choice1}}\fbox{world}

\item Using \texttt{\textbackslash ChoiceMenu} with \texttt{radio=false} does not produce this error:

    \fbox{hello}\fbox{\ChoiceMenu[radio=false, name=testfield2, bordersep=0pt]{}{Choice 1, Choice 2}}\fbox{world}

\item Using \texttt{\textbackslash CheckBox} also does not produce this error:

    \fbox{hello}\fbox{\CheckBox[name=testfield3, bordersep=0pt, height=36bp, width=36bp]{}}\fbox{world}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The following image shows what this looks like when viewed in Firefox using the PDF.js reader:

[image]

Is there any way I can stop this extra horizontal space from being added to every radio field? If not, then any information on why this occurs would still be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The spaces are deliberate and you would have to copy and adapt the `\@@Radio`  definition to get rid of them. Apart from this: the implementation of radio buttons are faulty, and I would suggest to use the new code in the PDF management see https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/263#issuecomment-1345291099

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much for that suggestion! The L3 code you linked to solves my issue, and I was able to compile it successfully using `xelatex`.